# find out windows in side-by-side mode

Tags: vba, excel

The "View Side By Side" and "Synchronous Scrolling" made the comparison of 2 spreadsheets easier than ever. However, there isn't a "Synchronous Switching tab" feature, so if I switch to a different tab in one of the workbooks and continue scrolling, the sync'ed scrolling become quite funny.

Well, I shouldn't complain, because it's all done manually, and I should use this feature wisely.

As a lazy developer, I would like to write some code to dig myself out: Can I write a macro to automate the worksheet switching on the peer window in side-by-side mode?

It breaks down to 2 steps:

1. how do I know if a window, most likely the ActiveWindow, is in side-by-side mode?
2. if it is, how do I tell which window is its peer?

I did my homework. It seems Excel is not very programming friendly on this feature. There are 3 methods

- `BreakSideBySide()`
- `CompareSideBySideWith(WindowName)`
- `ResetPositionsSideBySide()`

and 1 Boolean property

- `SyncScrollingSideBySide`

on the `Windows` collection related to this feature, but are insufficient to solve my questions.

Does anyone have any idea how to achieve this? Or, is it indeed impossible? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using the Workbook_SheetActivate event:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195710.aspx

if you put this code in your ThisWorkbook Object, then each time you change the active worksheet, it will...

1. Cycle through all open workbooks with a different name
2. Look for a worksheet with the same name as the sheet you just clicked on
3. Activate the worksheet in the other Workbook

   ```
   Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

       For i = 1 To Application.Workbooks.Count
           If Application.Workbooks(i).Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then

               Dim otherWB As Workbook
               Set otherWB = Application.Workbooks(i)
               otherWB.Sheets(Sh.Name).Activate

           End If
       Next

   End Sub
   ```

Note that this requires the worksheet to exist in all open workbooks.  An error will result if it does not.  However, you could easily add error handling to ignore workbooks with unfound corresponding worksheets.

Also note that it's probably best to use this when only two workbooks are open.  I have not looked into the other methods you mentioned, but there may exist a way to identify the two workbooks that are currently in side-by-side mode, at which point the code could shed its for loop and become more concise.

Comment: Thanks, Mr.Reband, for the code snippet of Activate a worksheet. However, my problem is to find out the peer window in side-by-side view. Yes, it would be easier if there are only 2 visible windows(or workbooks) - no choice is the best choice. But unfortunately, it is not always like that. Comparing 2 windows side-by-side, and tracking down differences in a 3rd file - this is what I usually do at work.

Comment: You could get around this by having a private workbook variable to store the name of the workbook being compared, then write a separate method which calls `CompareSideBySideWith` and also set the private workbook variable.  Then you would not need to loop over anything, and you could compare 2 files and track down differences in a 3rd.  Alternatively, you can open a new instance of Excel and keep your 3rd workbook there.

Comment: It seems the closest shot I can get is to loop over all the open workbooks, and switch the worksheet with the same name. That's saying, if the book has a sheet with that name. It isn't ideal, but I guess it won't hurt anyone :)